# awk - syntax error and unterminated regexp

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have this awk program

```
#! /usr/bin/awk

awk '{num = $1
        for (div = 2; div * div <= num; div++) {
            if (num % div == 0)
                break
        }
        if (num % div == 0)
                printf "Smallest divisor of %d is %d\n", num, div;
        else
                printf "%d is prime\n", num;
}'
```

when i run this, it gives me this error message

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ./blabla.awk
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ./blabla.awk
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unterminated regexp
```

I already check that i use the right interpreter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: IMHO could you please remove space between shebang and path of `awk` i haven't checked but it could be the issue.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i already try that but didn't work EDIT: the code just running didn't stop and didn't give any output.

Comment: While running it are you sure, you are passing Inpht_file to program? If not please pass it else awk program will be waiting condition for standard input.

Comment: yeah now its working thank you @RavinderSingh13, i use user muru code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't an awk program, that's a shell script containing an awk command. An awk program would look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

{num = $1
        for (div = 2; div * div <= num; div++) {
            if (num % div == 0)
                break
        }
        if (num % div == 0)
                printf "Smallest divisor of %d is %d\n", num, div;
        else
                printf "%d is prime\n", num;
}
```

That is, it would contain the awk code directly instead of calling awk.

Answer (score 1):

Though you could use bash or sh shebang like `#!/bin/bash` etc your awk code should work in it. If you want to stick with `awk` once then try removing space between shebang and path of awk eg--> `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` 
 once. Note I am on mobile so didn't test it.

Also remove `awk '` from your code, you need not to enclose your code in `awk '..........'` as per @oguz ismail nice reminder.